# How can I disable the Peephole-connection in the ConvLSTM2D() layer in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

How can I disable the Peephole-connection in the `keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D()` layer?

As I see the `ConvLSTM2D`: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/convolutional_recurrent.py#L902-L906

is based on this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04214v1

Where the Peephole is used as `Wci, Wcf, Wco` weights:

[image]

But as we know, LSTM layer can be without Peephole connection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory#Variants

So how can I disable the Peephole-connection in Keras (TensorFlow backend)?

Comment: `keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D()` didn't add peephole connection. You can check [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/29f27f333efb427830e62bec62fd79b444df4011/keras/layers/convolutional_recurrent.py#L727).